# Unable to embed networkx graph using matplotlib in customtk

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, customtkinter

I'm trying to embed a networkx graph in CustomTk, but the graph doesn't appear. When I use `plt.show()` I can see the graph in matplotlib pop-up menu, but not in GUI.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import networkx as nx

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(20, 0.125, seed=896803)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), node_size=4000, with_labels=True, font_size=20)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.margins(0.11)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.axis("off")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
plt.show()

def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate


button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if the window is
# closed with the window manager.
```

plt.show() image:
[image: plt.show() image]

figure on canvas:
[image: canvas image]

I'm not sure what's the issue when drawing on the canvas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/971#issuecomment-1371489896

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import networkx as nx

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title("Embedding in Tk")

#call fig ax exactly once
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


ax.margins(0.11)

#call the graphing module
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(20, 0.125, seed=896803)
#draw the graph, note the ax=ax at the end, this is the critical part, matplotlib needs to know onto which axis the graph is drawn
#otherwise it will just draw it in the spyder backend, without a care for your other elements
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), node_size=4000, with_labels=True, font_size=20,ax=ax)


canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)


def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate


button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if the window is
# closed with the window manager.
```